# Table of contents containing list of exercises in exam cls

Tags: table-of-contents, exam

I need  to include a toc in the first page of a multiple pages document containing exercises with solutions. I don't know if this should be named *table of contents* or rather  *list of exercises* (like *list of figures*)

[image]

MME:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,answers]{exam} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\qformat{\textbf {Exercise \thequestion} \hfill \thepoints}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{solution}
    \lipsum
    \end{solution}
    \newpage 

    \question
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{solution}
    \lipsum
    \end{solution}
    \newpage 

    \question
    \lipsum[3]
    \begin{solution}
    \lipsum
    \end{solution}

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is a question of taste. If it are al questions and answers it would be more useful to have "Table of Exercises"  or maybe "List of Exersises"

Comment: Try \renewcommand{\contentsname}{List of Exercises}  (sorry, I can't test it myself until I get MikTeX working again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion using `\tableofcontents`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=1,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=2.3em,
  dynnumwidth,
  pagenumberformat=\entryprefix{page~},
  pagenumberbox=\mbox
]{tocline}{exercise}
\newcommand*\entryprefix[2]{#1#2}

\qformat{%
  \textbf{Exercise~\thequestion}%
  \addxcontentsline{toc}{exercise}{Exercise~\thequestion}%
  \hfill\thepoints%
}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{List of Exercises}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\begin{questions}
\question
\lipsum[1]
\begin{solution}
\lipsum
\end{solution}
\clearpage

\question
\lipsum[2]
\begin{solution}
\lipsum
\end{solution}
\clearpage

\question
\lipsum[3]
\begin{solution}
\lipsum
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Suggestion using a new defined `\listofexercises`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=exercise,%
  types=exercises,%
  name=Exercise,%
  listname={List of Exercises},%
  tocentrystyle=tocline,%
  tocentryindent=0pt,%
  tocentrydynnumwidth,%
  tocentrypagenumberformat=\entryprefix{page~},%
  tocentrypagenumberbox=\mbox
]{exr}
\newcommand*\entryprefix[2]{#1#2}

\qformat{%
  \textbf{Exercise~\thequestion}%
  \addxcontentsline{exr}{exercise}{Exercise~\thequestion}%
  \hfill\thepoints%
}

\begin{document}
\listofexercises
\clearpage

\begin{questions}
\question
\lipsum[1]
\begin{solution}
\lipsum
\end{solution}
\clearpage

\question
\lipsum[2]
\begin{solution}
\lipsum
\end{solution}
\clearpage

\question
\lipsum[3]
\begin{solution}
\lipsum
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Both result in

[image]

Comment: The first method using `\tableofcontents` works fine but the second one using a new defined `\listofexercises` doesn't produce any list.

Comment: See my updated answer: `\addxcontentsline{exr}{exercise}{Exercise~\thequestion}` for the second method.

Comment: I tried the second method. However, the list of exercises is not clickable.  Is there any way to also accomplish this?

Comment: @RodrigoMorales Did you load package `hyperref`? If I load `hyperref` after the other packages the entries in list of exercises are clickable for me.

Comment: I didn't load it, @esdd. By loading it, the list of exercises is clickable. Thanks for pointing that out!